# rails search form that works on all pages of application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a search form which appears on all pages because I want someone to be able to search and be redirected to search results regardless of where they are on the site. To achieve this i placed the form in a partial which i included in the application layout. It looks like this

```
<form class="form-search center">
 <%=form_tag search_url, method: :get do%>
 <%=text_field_tag :query, params[:query] ,{:class=>"input-xxlarge search-query"}%>
 <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
<%end%>
</form>
```

I have created a controller called SearchResults with an index action to display the results.
The named route looks like this

```
match '/search',  to: 'search_results#index'
```

The search works perfectly fine on the search page, but cannot work anywhere else.My index action looks like this

```
class SearchResultsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @restaurants =  Restaurant.text_search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).per_page(3)

 end
end
```

I want to be able to redirect to this action whenever i carry out a search regardless of where i am in the application.The text_search method is defined in the restaurant model like so

```
def self.text_search(query)
if query.present?
  where("restaurant_name ilike :q or description ilike :q", q: "%#{query}%")

else
  scoped    
end
```

It doesn't work in that nothing happens when i search but if i go to the search page it returns the results.

I have noticed something interesting. When I search from the home page for a term like eats. The url looks like this `localhost:3000/?utf8=✓&query=eats` and when I search from the real search page which works perfectly it looks like this `localhost:3000/search?utf8=✓&query=eats`. How can i get it point to the latter url regardless of where am searching from?

Comment: What does "cannot work anywhere else" mean? Do you get an error? What is this error?

Comment: It doesn't display the results but appears to redirect.

Comment: You don't show your view, but I suspect one of the values `params[:querey]` or `params[:page]` is not being set. Did you check them?

Comment: what you should do in the `index action` is this `render js: "window.location = '#{search_path}'"` because it might be the case that its not able to throw the flow to that particular url so you can force that like this. Its not a sure solution but is worth a try.

Comment: Why there is a `form` inside `form` ?

Comment: The view works fine when i search from that specific view. but when i try to search from a different view nothing. I would expect it to redirect to the search view and display the search results.

Comment: To add class, you can do `<%=form_tag search_url, method: :get, class: 'form-search center' do%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do a proper routing entry for your search controller?

```
resources :search_results, :only => :index
```

And then in your search form you let it POST to `searches_path`. Then you don't have to fiddle around with this `:match` routing.

**Edit**

I also noticed that you `GET` your form. Technically it doesn't really matter, but it's not very clean. So maybe, you could do something like this:

```
resources :searches_results do
  post :query
end
```

And then in your controller you simply have the `query` function.

**Edit 2**

And I think the real problem here is that you are having is that you have a form tag in a form tag. The first form tag gets evaluated and it probably points to `/`. Therefore it works in the controller itself, but not anywhere else.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the nested form. Any ideas about how I can display a message when there are no results currently it just shows nothing.

Comment: In you view you can do something like `if @restaurants.size == 0`

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have a nested form.

```
<form class="form-search center">
  <%=form_tag search_path do%>
```

Get rid of the `form` you have in raw HTML and just let Rails generate it via the helper in the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

for my case i use somethig like this: in view

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => '/searchresults', :action => 'index')  , :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] ,{:class=>"input-xxlarge search-query"} %>
  <%= submit_tag 'search' %>
<% end %>
```

and in model

```
  q = "%#{params[:query]}%"
  where("restaurant_name LIKE ? or description LIKE ?", q, q)
```

Comment: Tried it. brings this error.   `ActionController::RoutingError at /
No route matches {:controller=>"search"}`

Comment: ooops, i forgot to check your controller name
`:controller => '/your_controller_name'`
this is answer to your error